# ie10+ Angular select issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fairly simple required which doesn't include ng-option and ng-repeat.So i create select box with two option for all browser evrything works fine but not on ie10+.
Any idea what is the root cause?

```
<select data-ng-model="ctrl.sort" data-ng-change="ctrl.matchSort(ctrl.sort)">
                               <option data-ng-value="p" data-ng-bind="sort.asc"></option>
                               <option data-ng-value="m" data-ng-bind="sort.desc"></option>
                             </select>
```

Select Drop down is getting created with empty option value string

```
<option value="?String:p"></option>


By Default : " ctrl.sort = 'p'; "
```

Comment: What is the expected value in place of `<option value="?String:p"></option>` ?

Comment: it should not come

Comment: What should come in that place? Empty value?

Comment: Drop down should get created with only two options p and m , this option with empty values is getting created unnecessary.

Comment: Can you try `ctrl.sort[0] = 'p'` ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your Angular model does not have a default value selected.  Hence, Angular may be inserting a default option.  In your model, you can use the following code:

```
$scope.ctrl.sort = 'default'
```

But here is a better way to do this:

```
$scope.ctrl = [{value: "default", name: "p"},
               {value: "p",       name: "p"},
               {value: "m",       name: "m"}];

$scope.ctrl.sort = "p";

<select name="ctrlselect"
        id="ctrlselect"
        data-ng-model="ctrl.sort"
        data-ng-change="ctrl.matchSort(ctrl.sort)"
        data-ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in ctrl">
</select>
```

Comment: it has default value

Comment: I don't see `$scope` being used when you assigned the default.

Comment: its because ctrl is alias name

Comment: Any other way apart from ng-options/ng-repeat

Comment: `ng-options` is the preferred way of doing this.  What is your reason for not wanting to use this method?

Comment: Dont want to create 10-12 different array in js as i have more than 10 drop down with different value.(some with 2 option and other with 3 max)

Comment: Very well.  This is how I would solve your problem.  Hard-coding options is not very flexible.